# USB stick for HDMI input

Tags: usb, hdmi

Looking for a cable for my **HDMI** port to use  as a **USB**

Comment: That doesn't exist. HDMI ports are one-way, while USB is two-way, and HDMI is controlled by the GPU instead of the chipset. That way, it cannot exist. The other way around does exist (USB capture cards) but not as you described it.

Comment: This question was closed on travel, so heres the comment I made there: There are a couple of possible reasons.  If you want to display some content stored on a USB stick you're out of luck, but if you're using a laptop with USB-C video out there are adaptors to give you HDMI.  If you think of it as a laptop adaptor and not a TV cable you're more likely to search for the right thing, and with more details of the actual problem we might be able to help.